Python_Pandas regex with vectorization is generating NaN
I have a data set which has columns that looks like this:

The Loc_Description column contains the name of towns and roads. The position of a town name with each string varies and is mostly dependent on whether the 6th character of the Loc_id is 'L' or not. I have tried using pandas vectorized operations to extract the town names into a new column called 'Town_Name'.
My aim is to generate this output:

Here is this method I tried to use to generate the desired output:
def wrangle_data(self, ih08_df):
    ih08_df['Town_Name'] = ih08_df['Loc_Description'].str.extract(r'^(.+?)(?=\s?\-)')
            trans_floc_rows = ih08_df['Loc_id'].str[5] !='L'
            ih08_df.loc[trans_floc_rows, 'Town_Name'] = ih08_df.loc[trans_floc_rows, 
                                                                'Loc_Description'].str.extract(r'(?<=\s\-)(.+?)(?=\s?\-)')

Instead I got this output showing NaN values for instances when the Loc.id's 6th character is not 'L'.

For some reason, str.extract(r'(?<=\s-)(.+?)(?=\s?-)') is not working. I have tried variations of the code using np.where() and np.select() without success. I would prefer to use a vectorized operation because the data set is quite large. Any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Can you add your inputs and expected outputs as text, not image?

Welcome to SO! Your question looks well asked, except for this: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Post them as text instead. Information unnecessarily posted as image may be considered missing debugging details. Reproducible input data is an essential part of an [mre], as recommended in [ask]. Copy-paste the output of print(df) instead.

Also a couple code lines have received too much indentation during your formatting.

is town name "Greece" correct?

Split the descriptions and get the appropriate value depending on whether the id contains 'L' as the 6th character (index 5):
df.loc[df["Loc id"].str[5] == "L", "Town_Name"] = (
    df["Loc_Description"].str.split().str[0]
)
df.loc[df["Loc id"].str[5] != "L", "Town_Name"] = (
    df["Loc_Description"].str.split().str[1].str.strip("-")
)

                  Loc id                Loc_Description Town_Name
0  9441-ET0043-1111-2222     753       -PORTAGE      -1   PORTAGE
1  9441-ET0043-1111-2223  75-445-1      -ALBION      -1    ALBION
2   9441-L0043-1111-2224      GREECE     -BELMONT RD-B2    GREECE
3   9441-L0043-1111-2225   ATTICA     -BELMONT RD   -B3    ATTICA

